# Use Generics properly

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, abstract-class

I am currently using an abstract class, which i am extending through another class called People

```
public abstract class MediaContainer<T> {
    abstract T DisplayName(T dispname);
}
```

but when i try to override it in the second i get an error

```
public class People<T> extends MediaContainer<T> {
    @Override public T DisplayName(T person){
        return System.out.println(person);
    }
}
```

Comment: what error? can you please post your error?

Comment: You should probably change the return type on that method from `T` to `void`.

Comment: I suggest you to use standard capitalization rules, e.g. "person" instead of "Person". Strange capitalization confuses people and the syntax highlighter.

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing the error is on this line:

```
return System.out.println(Person);
```

`println` returns `void`, and your `DisplayName` method needs to return `T`. If that method is only intended for printing to `System.out` as its name suggests, just change it to return `void`.

**NOTE:** Please make sure to provide more information in your questions in order to get better quality help and avoid downvotes. For compile errors, always include the error message and exact line it's happening on.

**EDIT:** As a side note, just based on the name of the class, it seems like you should use a bounded type parameter for your `People` class:

```
public class People<T extends Person> extends MediaContainer<T> { ... }
```

Or even resolve the type parameter:

```
public class People extends MediaContainer<Person> { ... }
```

That will allow `People`'s methods to interact with its contained objects as `Person` instances, calling `Person` methods, etc. This is assuming there's a corresponding `Person` class of course.